# default constructor not generated?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class T
{
    public:
    T(int h){item = h;}
    int item;    
};

int main()
{
    T a;
    cout << a.item << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error : cannot find `T::T()`, I know that the compiler does not generate an implicit constructor when I declare constructors with parameters, and this could be fixed by changing the constructor parameter to `int h = 0`, but is there any other way to get rid of error?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: You could pass a parameter to the ctor...

Comment: You have a specialized constructor without `explicit`, I think this would prohibit an automatically generated default constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What other way are you searching? In any case you have to define the default constructor if you are going to use it.

For example you could define your class the following way

```
class T
{
    public:
    T() = default;
    T(int h){item = h;}
    int item = 0;
};
```

Or you have to define the constructor explicitly

```
class T
{
    public:
    T() : item( 0 ) {}
    T(int h){item = h;}
    int item;
};
```

And one more example

```
class T
{
    public:
    T() : T( 0 ) {}
    T(int h){item = h;}
    int item;
};
```

Comment: i saw this example:  
Rectangle::Rectangle (int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) { } but i dont know what exactly this ":" syntax does

Comment: Does the `default` work?  What is that called anyway?  An implicit-explicit constructor?

Comment: @wallyk, A defaulted constructor. It just uses the one the compiler would generate.

Comment: @chris:  I have never seen that before.

Comment: and if i do this, and default constructor is called, what value will be in item variable?

Comment: @lllook In my example it will be set to 0.

Comment: I mean if I use version with T() = default; by using T() : item( 0 ) {}; its clear that item will be set to 0

Comment: @lllook, In the answer, still 0 because of the initializer on `item`. If you remove that, no initialization.

Comment: @wallyk: The colon syntax in constructors is called a [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). The T() `= default` forces the generation of the no argument constructor. You can read about that [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

Comment: @wallyk, It's a C++11 feature. Here's the section of the [Wikipedia C++11 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions).

Answer (score 7):

There is no default constructor because you provided one yourself. From [class.ctor], emphasis mine:

> A default constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. **If**
>   there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (8.4).

Since there is a user-declared constructor, there's no implicitly declared default. So you have three choices. You can *explicitly* declare a default:

```
T() = default;      // leaves item uninitialized
T() : item(0) { }   // initialize item to 0
```

Or you can provide a default argument like you suggested:

```
T(int i = 0) : item(i) { }
```

Or you can simply use the constructor you created:

```
T a(42);
```