# Compiler not recognizing the constructor, expects arguments and recognizes zero

Tags: c++, unix

I am trying to organize data into a binary tree and have created a struct to better organize the data. However, my compiler has this error message every time I try to run my code:

```
BinaryTree.cpp:41:37: error: no matching function for call to 'person::person()'
  node (person i, node * l, node * r){
                                     ^
BinaryTree.cpp:14:2: note: candidate: 'person::person(int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int)'
  person(int ss, int bd, string fn, string ln, int zc) {
  ^~~~~~
BinaryTree.cpp:14:2: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 0 provided
BinaryTree.cpp:10:8: note: candidate: 'person::person(const person&)'
 struct person {
        ^~~~~~
BinaryTree.cpp:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
BinaryTree.cpp:10:8: note: candidate: 'person::person(person&&)'
BinaryTree.cpp:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

The lines of code it is referring to, are these structs I created. I have used the person struct before and it works just fine so I am confused as to my error.

```
struct person {
    int socialSecurity, birthDate, zipCode;
    string firstName, lastName;
person(int ss, int bd, string fn, string ln, int zc) {
    socialSecurity = ss;
    birthDate = bd;
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    zipCode = zc;
}
};

struct node {
    person info;
    node * left, * right;

node (person i, node * l, node * r){
    info = i;
    left = l;
    right = r;
    }
};
```

I am a bit new to this so if you need more code to help me figure out what is wrong Ill try to provide as much as I can.

Comment: You need to initialize the data member `info` (in member initializer list) like `node (person i, node * l, node * r) : info(i) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you defined a non-default constructor, the compiler will not generate a default constructor, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor for more info.
To solve this, see [default constructor not generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718472/default-constructor-not-generated).